# Property with validation and convertion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop

This might be a basic question, but I would like to know best practice.
I have a public property which takes in a value as an Integer. If that
value by accident would be a String, could I in my property do validation
and convertion on the fly, so the output becomes an Integer, without
my script failing? Or is it best to make shure to operate with the 
right datatype before passing it in the property?

This is my property:

```
Public Property Quantity() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Quantity
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_Quantity = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Best regards!

Comment: you will get an error when you compile.its not possible in c#

Answer (score 1):

> If that value by accident would be a String,

Such accident cannot happen in a strongly typed language because the compiler will tell you that you cannot assign a string value to an integer property. Actually you could shorten your code a little by using an [Auto-Implemented Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx):

```
Property Quantity As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The property cannot be a string. Either the code will not compile, or if you don't have Option Strict/Infer on (and you really should!) the runtime conversion to Integer will fail, causing an exception.